# Acceleo M2T (Cannot access to the my matamodele attributes , references .. )

Tags: java, emf, acceleo

I am developing a M2T generator in Acceleo (in Obeo Designer).
I have created my metamodel based on *.ecore (pfe.ecore ) and then I have created an instance model in runtime (MyModels.pfe) using Sirius.

Now I am trying to generate the java code of MyModels.pfe using Accelo -the class root is InterationSpatiale.

I want to generate a *.java for each of my classes in the diagram
here is my generate.mtl file

```
 [comment encoding = UTF-8 /]
[module generate('http://www.example.org/pfe')/]
[template public generateElement(myinteractionspatiale : 
InteractionSpatiale)]
[comment @main/]
[file (myinteractionspatiale.name.concat('.java'), false, 'UTF-8')]

public class [myinteractionspatiale.name/] {

[for (aEAttribute : ecore :: EAttribute | 
 myinteractionspatiale.eClass().eAllAttributes)]
   [aEAttribute.eType.instanceClassName/] [aEAttribute.name/];
[/for]
[for (aEReference : EReference 
|myinteractionspatiale.eClass().eAllReferences)]
  [aEReference.eReferenceType.name/] [aEReference.name/];
[/for]
[for (aEAttribute : EAttribute | 
myinteractionspatiale.eClass().eAllAttributes)]
  public [aEAttribute.eType.instanceClassName/] 
  get[aEAttribute.name.toUpperFirst()/] () {
    return this.[aEAttribute.name/];
  }
 [/for]
 [for (aEAttribute : EAttribute | 
 myinteractionspatiale.eClass().eAllAttributes)]
   public void set[aEAttribute.name.toUpperFirst()/] 
   ([aEAttribute.eType.instanceClassName/] [aEAttribute.name/]) {
    this.[aEAttribute.name/] = [aEAttribute.name/];
  }
 [/for]

 [for (aEReference : EReference | 
 myinteractionspatiale.eClass().eAllReferences)]
   public [aEReference.eReferenceType.name/] 
  get[aEReference.name.toUpperFirst()/] () {
    return this.[aEReference.name/];
  }
 [/for]

 [for (aEReference : EReference | 
  myinteractionspatiale.eClass().eAllReferences)]
  public void set[aEReference.name.toUpperFirst()/] 
  ([aEReference.eReferenceType.name/] [aEReference.name/]) {
    this.[aEReference.name/] = [aEReference.name/];}
 [/for]

[for (aEOperation : EOperation | 
myinteractionspatiale.eClass().eAllOperations)]
  public [aEOperation.eType.instanceClassName/] [aEOperation.name/] () {
    }
[/for]

}
 [/file]

[/template]
```

the generated file I got App.java is

```
public class App {

java.lang.String name;
Entite entite;
Evenement evenement;
SystemeCoordonnees systemecoordonnees;
TacheSysteme tachesysteme;
RelationSpatiale relationspatiale;
InteractionSpatiale interactionspatiale;
public java.lang.String getName () {
    return this.name;
}
public void setName (java.lang.String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Entite getEntite () {
    return this.entite;
}
public Evenement getEvenement () {
    return this.evenement;
}
public SystemeCoordonnees getSystemecoordonnees () {
    return this.systemecoordonnees;
}
public TacheSysteme getTachesysteme () {
    return this.tachesysteme;
}
public RelationSpatiale getRelationspatiale () {
    return this.relationspatiale;
}
public InteractionSpatiale getInteractionspatiale () {
    return this.interactionspatiale;
}

public void setEntite (Entite entite) {
    this.entite = entite;
}
public void setEvenement (Evenement evenement) {
    this.evenement = evenement;
}
public void setSystemecoordonnees (SystemeCoordonnees systemecoordonnees) 
{
    this.systemecoordonnees = systemecoordonnees;
}
public void setTachesysteme (TacheSysteme tachesysteme) {
    this.tachesysteme = tachesysteme;
}
public void setRelationspatiale (RelationSpatiale relationspatiale) {
    this.relationspatiale = relationspatiale;
}
public void setInteractionspatiale (InteractionSpatiale 
interactionspatiale) {
    this.interactionspatiale = interactionspatiale;
}
}
```

**But** what I really wanted is to have a file for each class of the model MyModels.pfe not just the java file of the root class.

kindly check the MyModels.pfe  to have an idea about  about what I want to generate.
[ScreenShot of MyModels.pfe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VBch.png)

Any help is much appreciated on how to iterate and have a file for each class with its attributes and their values[EFixe.java, EMobile.java ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
aEClass : InteractionSpatiale
```

is misleading, you should call it something like myInteractionSpatiale because your parameter is an instance of InteractionSpatiale (in the sense of Java/Acceleo typing).

In the sense of EMF typing, your myInteractionSpatiale is an EObject that is an instance of the EClass "InteractionSpatiale" you have defined in your metamodel pfe.ecore

I understand you want to iterate on the attributes of this EClass:

```
myInteractionSpatiale.eClass().getAllAttributes()
```

Comment: Hi user1292456 , Thank you so much for your fast replay , it was soo helpful ! now I have generated just the java file of the root class , what I really want is the java files of the each class of the model ,  kindly check the post above , I have updated it  to give more details about my concern . I really appreciate your effort to help me

Comment: well I don't see what is your problem now. Your template takes an InteractionSpatiale as input and outputs a corresponding Java file of your choice.
Simply create other templates for your other types (or better, generify you current template so it can take any EObject conforming to an EClass of your metamodel pfe.ecore) and call it recursively on the contents (see myInteractionSpatiale.eAllContents), starting from your root element (i.e. myInteractionSpatiale)

Comment: Great I got you well !!, but what I had as an issue (to be more explicit ) I cannot access my attributes value that I have initialized before. I have tried   [aEAttribute->any(true).value ] and other alternative but in vain !!  could you help me access the value of each of my attributes.

Comment: to retrieve the value of an EAttribute of an EObject, you want to use EObject#eGet(EStructuralFeature)

Comment: Thank you so much! it works perfectly. I used [myInteractionSpatiale.eGet(aEAttribute)/];

Comment: Hi, As you have mentioned above: I have created a template for each class in different module files and I tried to call them in the main *.mtl  module after importing all the modules. In the main template that takes an InteractionSpatiale as input and a java file as output: I called template [generateEntiteFixe (p )/] but the problem is the parameter p  to pass as input to the template. I tried to extract it from the root (myInteractionSpatiale )  :[ myInteractionSpatiale.eContents().eClass().name  ] - to follow in the next comment

Comment: got this in the java file : FixeEMobileEvenEMobileEFixeTacheSystemeRelationSpatiale which is the name of all my classes concatinated . As I need to reference  each class of my model , I tried this [myInteractionSpatiale.eContents().eClass()->any(name = 'EFixe')/] I got  :  org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl@29d80d2b (name: EFixe) (instanceClassName: null) (abstract: false, interface: false.So to call the template : [generateEntiteFixe (myInteractionSpatiale.eContents().eClass()->any(name = 'EFixe')/] but it doesn't execute or generate the code of the generateEntiteFixe

Comment: what's wrong or how can I do it correctly __any help is much appreciated , I apologize for bothering you

Comment: I don't understand why to iterate on your model you call eClass() : this is to navigate from a model to the metamodel it conforms to.
You probably want to use a for loop on myInteractionSpatiale.eContents instead.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative for the last comment (not the most optimized )

for each class , I create a let block in the main module to call different templates :

```
[let p : EFixe = myInteractionSpatiale.entite->any(oclIsKindOf(EFixe)) ]
[generateEntiteFixe (p)/]
[/let]
```

Regards